# Decompose the set of polynomials on $[0,1]$ in two subsets each not separating measures

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials

It is well-known by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that if we consider the set of finite measures $\mathcal{M}_f([0,1])$ on $[0,1]$ the following is true for $\mu_1, \mu_2 \in \mathcal{M}_f([0,1])$:
\begin{equation}
 \mu_1 = \mu_2 \Leftrightarrow \int \mu_1(dx) \, p(x) = \int \mu_2(dx) \, p(x) \quad \forall p \in P ,
\end{equation}
where $P$ is the set of polynomials $P = \{p:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \ | \ p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i \text{ for some } a_i \in \mathbb{R}, 0\leq i \leq n\}$. Write for abbreviation:
\begin{equation} \mu_1(p) = \int \mu_1(dx) \, p(x) . \end{equation}

**Question**: Are there two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $P$ covering $P$: $P = A\cup B$ such that for some $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3 \in \mathcal{M}_f([0,1])$
\begin{equation}
 \mu_1(p) = \mu_2(p) \ \forall p \in A \ \text{  and  }\ \mu_2(p) = \mu_3(p) \ \forall p \in B ,
\end{equation}
but $\mu_1 \neq \mu_3$ (so there are $p \in P$ such that $\mu_1(p) \neq \mu_3(p)$). In other words, neither $A$ nor $B$ is separating points even though $A \cup B$ is.

Possible modifications:

1. Consider a discrete set instead of $[0,1]$.
2. Consider a decomposition of $P$ into finitely many subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If set $A$ doesn't separate $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, neither does its linear span.
So you can replace $A, B$ by their linear spans and have two linear subspaces
whose union is $P$.  But if a vector space is the union of two linear subspaces, 
one of them is the whole space.